# Can I develop Ios applications on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, windows-10

I own a windows 10 machine and recently I started studying programming for IOS, now a Mac doesn't seem to fit in my budget and this is just to start developing a service that is cross platform.

Comment: Yes, technically you could develop ios apps on a PC.
The problem is you can't really compile them without running the proper build chain (xCode) which isn't there for windows environments. so you'll still need a mac in order to actually compile for the ios device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can develop(write code) using Visual studio + xamarin(https://xamarin.com/), but you still need mac machine to compile your code

https://xamarin.com/visual-studio